# how can i diagnose exception in window 7 release mode compilation with VC 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, exception, windows-7, release-mode

i have strange problem , my application (exe) is working fine in debug mode in windows 7 
but stop to work with exception when compiling in release mode .
how can i debug the program to find what is causing the exception this is application with more then 300,000 lines of code ..

Comment: Is that .NET or C++? Or something different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile in Release mode but create the .pdb files: [How to generate PDB’s for .net managed projects in release mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585397/how-to-generate-pdbs-for-net-managed-projects-in-release-mode)

Deploy the .pdb files to same folder as the .exe.

Then attach to process.

Comment: i cant find how to create PDB files , i guess they talking about c#
im using c++

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the projects settings which are different for debug and release modes, maybe you will find an answer there.
2. Compile release mode with debug information and turn off optimization. You will have debug version compiled with release defines. If it fails the debugger will show you bad place.
3. Just turn off optimization. Once upon a time that was an issue for me. In this case it will be really hard to find out the cause.
4. Create PDBs, it can be done for native C++ too.